# In Windows 10, how can we determine which virtual desktop a window belongs to?

Tags: windows, screen-capture, windows-10, virtual-desktop

Concerning Windows 10 and its new virtual desktop feature, is there a way to determine which virtual desktop a particular window belongs to? And, which virtual desktop is active?

The problem can be seen using the ***Snipping Tool***. Open the tool and select a **New / Window Snip**. As you move the mouse around, the snipping tool ***highlights areas where there is no window***, but there is a window at that location on another virtual desktop.

[In this picture, the Snipping Tool is highlighting an empty spot.](http://pixelmetrics.com/Temp/Snip1.png)

Snipping Tool doesn't know which virtual desktop a particular window is on.

[Here's the same question on MSDN Forums, unanswered, but with lots of additional detail.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/406e938e-97d8-478b-8bbe-19fa24f5c358/windows-10-tp-q-is-there-an-c-api-to-use-with-the-w10-virtual-desktop-features?forum=windowssdk#406e938e-97d8-478b-8bbe-19fa24f5c358)

Sorry, my status isn't high enough to insert images or include more links.

Comment: There is no SDK published for Windows 10 yet.

Comment: Right, which doesn't give us much time to fix things if Windows 10 is to be released this summer :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Windows SDK Support Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/) posted a [C# demo to switch Desktops](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/winsdk/archive/2015/09/10/virtual-desktop-switching-in-windows-10.aspx) via [IVirtualDesktopManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Mt186440%28v=VS.85%29.aspx):

```cs
    [ComImport, InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown), Guid("a5cd92ff-29be-454c-8d04-d82879fb3f1b")]
    [System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
    public interface IVirtualDesktopManager
    {
    [PreserveSig]
    int IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(
        [In] IntPtr TopLevelWindow,
        [Out] out int OnCurrentDesktop
        );
    [PreserveSig]
    int GetWindowDesktopId(
        [In] IntPtr TopLevelWindow,
        [Out] out Guid CurrentDesktop
        );

    [PreserveSig]
    int MoveWindowToDesktop(
        [In] IntPtr TopLevelWindow,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]
        [In]Guid CurrentDesktop
        );
    }
    
    [ComImport, Guid("aa509086-5ca9-4c25-8f95-589d3c07b48a")]
    public class CVirtualDesktopManager
    {
    
    }
    public class VirtualDesktopManager
    {
        public VirtualDesktopManager()
        {
            cmanager = new CVirtualDesktopManager();
            manager = (IVirtualDesktopManager)cmanager;
        }
        ~VirtualDesktopManager()
        {
            manager = null;
            cmanager = null;
        }
        private CVirtualDesktopManager cmanager = null;
        private IVirtualDesktopManager manager;
    
        public bool IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(IntPtr TopLevelWindow)
        {
            int result;
            int hr;
            if ((hr = manager.IsWindowOnCurrentVirtualDesktop(TopLevelWindow, out result)) != 0)
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
            return result != 0;
        }
    
        public Guid GetWindowDesktopId(IntPtr TopLevelWindow)
        {
            Guid result;
            int hr;
            if ((hr = manager.GetWindowDesktopId(TopLevelWindow, out result)) != 0)
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
            return result;
        }
    
        public void MoveWindowToDesktop(IntPtr TopLevelWindow, Guid CurrentDesktop)
        {
            int hr;
            if ((hr = manager.MoveWindowToDesktop(TopLevelWindow, CurrentDesktop)) != 0)
            {
                Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(hr);
            }
        }
    }
```

Call `GetWindowDesktopId` to get the Desktop GUID.

Comment: Googling for `IVirtualDesktopManager` gives the MSDN page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/Mt186440(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, magicandre, for explaining how and where you got that answer, it was hard work, not magic :)

Comment: I saw it in the RSS feed of the blog. Also subscribe to it to get notified about some nice samples, Hotfixes and other tricks.